# Are 'Magh' and 'Ang' tribes of RigVeda?

Tags: rig-veda

There are various tribes of RigVeda is described in later scriptures but none of them mentions Ang and Magh as RigVedic tribe. Most of the scriptures mentions Maghadh (whose inhabitants are called Magh) and Ang as area/ country located in present Bihar,but not recognised as RigVedic. Even in AtharvaVeda Maghadh is considered to be outside of RigVedic Aryan sphere.

But RigVeda is a text of very ancient origin and consisting of a language from which classical Sanskrit emerged.Yet Sanskrit helps us only in a limited way to understand RigVedic language because it contains a large number of archaic words and uses. The best way to understand RigVeda is to derive the meaning of words from the internal structure of its corpus. Many words are repeated at several places and it gives us an opportunity to extract a viable meaning by extrapolating the contexts. Magh and Ang are two words here which appears quite frequently in RigVeda and mostly meaning as tribes of great importance.

My question here is - Can it be proved or disproved that Magh and Ang are tribes from the facts described in Rigveda only?

Comment: @bhaskar can you please elaborate a bit on "Aryan sphere". Thanks.

Comment: and what does your question have to do with Hinduism?

Comment: @Just_Do_It   Here I mean Vedic Aryan , as many scripture portray Maghadh as inferior kind of and enimical  community _ 1. Some diseases are sent towards Maghadh ( Atharva Veda) 2, Maghadha uses cruel language,mridhvaca (Satpath Brahman)3, rusted food is for Maghadha ( Yajur Veda), however it is not the main theme of the question.

Comment: @Swami Vishvananda Does your version of Hinduism exclude RigVeda ?

Comment: No, it does not exclude the Rig Veda, but 'proving' or 'disproving' events as historical facts is the realm of archeology/anthropology and not the realm of religious discourse.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda  RigVeda is a religious discourse of Hinduism with a high esteem. Interpretation  and re-interpretation  of all scriptures  is an ongoing process in the realm of Hinduism. The above question is simply related with interpretation  of RigVeda. Do you mean to say it should not be interpreted in it's own right ?